# Put icon into search bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, search, icons

I am trying to have a search icon only in my nav bar which is up there, but I want a search bar to drop down when the search icon is clicked on I don't know what I'm doing with this code:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">

        <a href="#navs" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span style="color:white" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"/>
        </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li>
                <input type="hidden" name="cx" />
                <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8" />
                <input type="text" name="q" size="25" />
                <input type="submit" name="sa" value="Search" />


            </form>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Begin with the basics: http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp after you understand the basics of HTML you can learn a little more about CSS: http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp after you have learned the basics then you can learn more about navbars here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp

Comment: Goto http://bootsnipp.com and you will find good examples over there.

Comment: Try something like this: http://www.bootply.com/rX9b6QFM6j

Answer (score 1):

Could u use jquery?  Make `.dropdown-menu { display: none; }` and then use jquery and do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function(){
    $(".dropdown-menu").toggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot but do you know how i would close it?

Comment: you can use `.toggle();` instead of `.show()`.  basically it just toggles between hide/show.  If before click the element is hidden it will show.  If it's visible it will hide.  So in your css whatever you want your initial view to be just set it!  `.toggle()` is definitely what you are looking for.